# French equivalent of U-S-A! cheer?

Tags: expressions

I should know this, but I don't quite have it. Americans will, on occasion, chant U-S-A! U-S-A! U-S-A! when cheering on national sport teams or at patriotic rallies. What would the French equivalent be? I know a lot of such for French football, but none of those seem applicable to France itself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: « Allez les bleus » semble être le plus populaire

Comment: Just like U-S-A! U-S-A! U-S-A! has a specific rhythm to it when it's chanted by supporters, so does Allez les Bleus !  Allez les Bleus !  Allez and les should be lengthened and bleus clipped with glottal closure.  Something like: /ale:le:bløʔ/.  You can hear it there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeonwSgg61Q

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Allez les bleus !*** already suggested by cl-r in a comment is common when supporting a national team but is only used when a sport team is involved.

For other kinds of patriotic rallies, singing the ***Marseillaise*** would be the usual way to show support.

Comment: You also have this very famous and popular song from Johnny Hallyday called "Tous ensemble" :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ku9s0CKbpY

Answer (score 4):

For a three syllable (like "U-S-A!") patriotic exclamation, there's "Vive La France!" but, as mentioned in [*lawless.com*'s entry for that expression](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/vive-la-france/):

> You probably won’t hear the patriotic exclamation Vive la France !
>   more than a few times a year [as] it tends to be reserved for occasions
>   like Bastille Day, [French elections](https://youtu.be/RLESm5YlDjE), international sports, and, sadly,
>   national tragedy.(the "French elections" link to *youtube* was also found in that same *lawless.com* entry)

Please note, however, that in addition to *lawless.com*'s caution about "probably [not hearing] ... 'Vive la France!' more than a few times a year," I would also caution that the following videos that I found of people **repeatedly** chanting these three syllables **in organized unison** (as is done with "U-S-A!") were **not** filmed in France, which could mean that this staccato/repetitive/in unison use of "Vive La France! Vive La France! Vive La France!" is a "non-French-native" way of paying homage to and showing solidarity with France (and not one that is typically used in France by French natives):

[General de Gaulle in Mexico](https://www.britishpathe.com/video/general-de-gaulle-visits-mexico-aka-de-gaulle-in-m) (where at the very beginning it sounds to me like the crowd is chanting "Vive la France!") (from *britishpathe.com*)

[Solidarity with France shown in London following the November 2015 Paris attacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uzir4iEBy0) (posted by *guardianwitness* on *youtube*)

Comment: Excellent observation. La Marseillaise seems the best "usage" equivalent, though it does not directly equate to a simple cheer. I wish I could select both of these answers as correct. This was what I was trying to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, heads of state or other polititians can and sometimes say *Vive la France !* in speeches, but this is definitely not something a French crowd will chant.

Answer (score -3):

One can say  "Allez les Bleus !" but a lot of people think they are saying "Aller les Bleus !"; this last spelling (on banners for instance) is not correct ([ref.](https://rugbyaxvdefrance.com/aller-les-bleus-ou-allez-les-bleus/)).

It is also possible to say "Allez les bleus, allez la France" ([ref.](https://www.ina.fr/video/I00014704)). Of course you can also write  "Allez la France !" on  banners and say it too ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1DIEZ_enFR854FR875&q=allez+la+france&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0lJH-4-_nAhWK4YUKHWhuBA4QsAR6BAgHEAE&biw=1920&bih=1007)).

Comment: How is this interesting since we already have [a better answer with the same information](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41330/82)?

Comment: @Evpok It is not complete: is not mentionned that the form "Aller…" is not correct; neither is it mentioned that you can say "Allez la France !". It is not a "better" answer, nor is mine "better" : neither is complete.

Comment: I never heard anyone chant “Allez la France” so I don't think that extra part is correct. Also the remark on *aller* is off-topic.

Comment: @Evpok This is actually the title of [a french song](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dajci0Wub9W8&ved=2ahUKEwi10LaazPTnAhUtNOwKHUm_DCEQyCkwAnoECAoQHw&usg=AOvVaw31SF7xWVzukOBNcHcI0P9_), I certainly won't call it incorrect